# Apache-Solr: JSP support not configured

Tags: apache, jsp, solr, jetty

I'm using apache-solr from bitnami I downloaded a week ago. Everything is going fine about indexing and searching, but I can't execute jsp files.

When I try to open main.jsp, the file isn't executed, the browser only shows the codes I wrote on main.jsp. Here's the codes on main.jsp I got from a tutorial website:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using GET and POST Method to Read Form Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Using GET Method to Read Form Data</h1>
<ul>
<li><p><b>First Name:</b>
    <%= request.getParameter("first_name")%>
</p></li>
<li><p><b>Last  Name:</b>
    <%= request.getParameter("last_name")%>
</p></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And then, when I try to open /solr/admin/stats.jsp, it says:

```
>HTTP ERROR 500
>
>Problem accessing /solr/admin/stats.jsp. Reason:
>
>    JSP support not configured
>
>Powered by Jetty://
```

So, then I tried to configure the JSP support by typing:

```
>$ java -jar jetty.jar OPTIONS=Server,jsp
```

in Cygwin. But it says:

```
>Error: Unable to access jarfile jetty.jar
```

I've tried to add this snippet in jetty.xml:

```
<Call class="java.lang.System"  name="setProperty">
    <Arg>org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199</Arg>
    <Arg>true</Arg>
</Call>
```

And after restarting the apache and solr, it doesn't resolving my problem, either. I want to try adding this snippet to start.ini:

```
>-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true
```

But, I can't find start.ini.

Please help me.

Comment: This might help: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201205.mbox/%3CCBD8145F.C53%25nvijayap@tibco.com%3E ?

Comment: try start.jar in place of jetty.jar in one of your examples above